How to make sure state updates that are fired off in succession all execute
If I have multiple state updates that all fire off in rapid succession, the initial state updates will not fully update because they will be overridden by later state updates. How can I make it so that all state updates fully execute. Here is some code to get a rough idea of what I mean:
            .start(() => {

              this.setState({message: "started"})

            })
            .progress(() => {
      
              this.setState({message: "progress"})}

            .finish(() => {

              this.setState({message: "finished"})

            })
    

where these functions are chained together and will execute rapidly one after another. How can I make it so all state updates execute. Is there a cleaner way than just making each state update return a promise and awaiting them?

react only uses the latest state for the render. so if more than one change happens between the render (e.g. fast running functions) they wont trigger the rerender which potentially triggers some additional logic in the useEffects.
Unfortunatly, I'm not aware of a way to override this behavior so only workarounds come to mind. What do you mean with "fully execute"? Or maybe better: Why does it matter that the state is "fully executed"? Could you potentially ignore the render of the in between states as long as the logic required is run?

@JWittmeyer the usecase here is essentially building out a UI that logs the progress of a process. I want every step to be logged but these steps happen so fast that the state update to log some steps just get overridden. In this usecase I wouldnt be able to ignore the render of the in between states.

Not sure what setState is used for, for simplicity sake a version with a new log as own state. This idea (though with some changes) can also be applied to the setState if it's used for logging as well:
const [fullLog,setFullLog] = useState<string[]>([]);
then in your logic call the setter with a different approach (using a function instead).

            .start(() => {
              setFullLog(current =>[...current ,"started"])
              this.setState({message: "started"})

            })
            .progress(() => {
              setFullLog(current =>[...current ,"processed"])      
              this.setState({message: "progress"})}

            .finish(() => {
              setFullLog(current =>[...current ,"finished"])
              this.setState({message: "finished"})

            })

In short: setFullLog([...fullLog, newLog]) sets the value based on the value in the state variable. setFullLog(current =>[...current ,newLog]) sets the value based on the current/previous state value. So if two state changes happen between a render, the first version doesn't get the update for the fullLog variable while the second option always has the actual current value (not the current value of the variable).
Further reading on state setter: https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#setstate
